# How to get a the sum of multiple arrays within an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, for-loop, sum

I was wondering how you get the sum of multiple arrays within an array of objects. My code is as follows:

```
const employeeList = [    

    {
    "name": "Ahmed",
    "scores": [
    "5",
    "1",
    "4",
    "4",
    "5",
    "1",
    "2",
    "5",
    "4",
    "1"
    ]
    },
    {
    "name": "Jacob Deming",
    "scores": [
    "4",
    "2",
    "5",
    "1",
    "3",
    "2",
    "2",
    "1",
    "3",
    "2"
    ]
    }];

var sum = 0;

for(let i = 0; i < employeeList.length; i++){
  var eachScore = employeeList[i].scores;
  const b = eachScore.map(Number);
  console.log(b);

  sum += parseInt(b);//this is the code that doesn't work

}

console.log(sum);
```

So the problem is, I can get the two arrays to console log but I'm not sure how to go about summing up each array.. When I do sum += parseInt(b), it just logs how many items are in the array(9). and When I do without parseInt, it concats the numbers together but doesn't sum them up.. I would like to use a .split() method to split the arrays and sum them up individually but I haven't quite figured out how to do it yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `b` is an array of numbers, you can't meaningfully use `+` with it unless you want a comma-joined string. The most functional way to sum up an array is to use `reduce`, which can be used to iterate over its items and add them all to the accumulator:

```
b.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
```

If you want to know the partial sums, I'd use `.map` to transform each object in the `employeeList` array into the sum of their scores, by extracting the `scores` property and using `reduce` to sum them all up:

```js
const employeeList=[{"name":"Ahmed","scores":["5","1","4","4","5","1","2","5","4","1"]},{"name":"Jacob Deming","scores":["4","2","5","1","3","2","2","1","3","2"]}]

const sum = (a, b) => Number(a) + Number(b);
const output = employeeList.map(({ scores }) => scores.reduce(sum));
console.log(output);
// If you want to sum up the results into a single number as well:
console.log(output.reduce(sum));
```

Comment: thank you so much for the explanation. this helps a ton!

Answer (score 0):

You can use array reduce to calculate the sum:

```js
const employeeList = [    
{
  "name": "Ahmed",
  "scores": [
  "5",
  "1",
  "4",
  "4",
  "5",
  "1",
  "2",
  "5",
  "4",
  "1"
  ]
},
{
  "name": "Jacob Deming",
  "scores": [
  "4",
  "2",
  "5",
  "1",
  "3",
  "2",
  "2",
  "1",
  "3",
  "2"
  ]
}];

var sum = 0;

for(let i = 0; i < employeeList.length; i++){
  let eachScore = employeeList[i].scores;
  let b = eachScore.reduce((total,current)=>{
    total += +current;
    return total;
  },0);
  console.log(b);

  sum += b;
}

console.log(sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help:

```
var parsedScores = [];
var scores = [
   "4","2","5","1","3","2","2","1","3","2"
];
let total = 0;
scores.forEach(el => {
   parsedScores.push(parseInt(el))
})
for (let score in parsedScores) {
   total += parsedScores[score]
}
console.log(total);
```