# ReactJS: Help debugging? Sum of each array NOT columns

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

Need help with figuring out how to get the sum of multiple arrays.

This is my Data outputting from the console.log:

```
(4) [empty, Array(1), Array(1), Array(4)]
1: [50, 30]
2: [100, 100, 50]
3: (4) [500, 10, 50, 300]
```

Expected output:

```
1: [80] 
2: [250] 
3: [860]
```

Methods used:

1. This code below doesn't work, it's just the columns of each row

   ```
   const savingsTotal = saveID[0].map((x, idx) => saveID.reduce((sum, curr) => sum + curr[idx], 0));
   ```

code source : [How to calculate the sum of multiple arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54712774/how-to-calculate-the-sum-of-multiple-arrays)

2. This code gives me a weird string:

   ```
    const savingsTotal = saveID.reduce((sum, value) =>  sum += value, 0)
   ```

Output: `050100500,10,50,300`

3. Thought if I list with a key that would work, eg [saved: 500], but
   it didn't up working either.

   ```
    const savingsTotal = saveID.map(({saved}) => saved.reduce((sum, value) => sum += value, 0))
   ```

Output: breaks code, can't find [saved : 500] due to the previous function which is:

```
  if (save.length > 0 ) { 
  const saveID = save.reduce((savedAmount, { goal_id, saved }) => {
    (savedAmount[goal_id] = savedAmount[goal_id] || []).push({"saved": saved});
    return savedAmount;
  }, []); ****Changed the .push so I would be able to add a key, normally it's without.
```

code source:  [How to get a the sum of multiple arrays within an array of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53038264/how-to-get-a-the-sum-of-multiple-arrays-within-an-array-of-objects)

Can someone help me out with the logic?

Comment: The expected output doesn't even sum up. In the first case [50, 30] should be [80] not [70] and the third case [500, 10, 50, 300] should be [860] not [850]. Did you make a mistake or I'm missing something here?

Comment: Whoops, my bad I must've done the math wrong on my part.

Comment: not sure if you miss-typed your expected result, data.map(i=>i.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)) i get [0, 80, 250, 860]

Comment: The solution is so much simpler than what you've attempted.  just reduce with `(accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue`.  The example in [the docs for Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) provides a summation example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Map through the original array of arrays. then use `reduce` to get the respective sum of their parts:

```js
const ar = [[50, 30], [100, 100, 50], [500, 10, 50, 300]];
const sum_array = ar.map(item => item.reduce((acc, val) => acc + val, 0))
console.log(sum_array)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can loop over the outer array and use `reduce` to find the sum of each constituent array.

```js
const arr = [, [50, 30],[100, 100, 50], [500, 10, 50, 300]];
for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
  if(Array.isArray(arr[i])){
    console.log(i + ': ' + arr[i].reduce((acc,curr)=>acc+curr, 0));
  }
}
```

If you want to produce a result array instead of just printing it, you can use `map`.

```js
const arr = [, [50, 30],[100, 100, 50], [500, 10, 50, 300]];
const res = arr.map(x => x.reduce((acc,curr)=>acc+curr, 0));
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
let arr = [10, 70],
    arr2 = [100, 100, 50],
    arr3 = [500, 10, 50, 300]

console.log(arr.reduce((sum, carry) => sum + carry));
console.log(arr2.reduce((sum, carry) => sum + carry));
console.log(arr3.reduce((sum, carry) => sum + carry));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I would do each individual array, however, the issue my program is expecting multiple arrays in the future. I'm trying to achieve a singular function that produces sums of multiple arrays.

Comment: Ok, I can draft a function like that for you man. Would each array be in a containing array? Something like: [ [10, 70], [100, 100, 50], [500, 10, 50, 300] ] and after the function runs on this array, it gives another array containing the sum, like [80, 250, 860]? If not, how would the data be structured? Let me know so I can draft a codepen for you :)